# Connected to WiFi but can’t access internet

Tags: networking, wireless, laptop, asus

Sorry for the terrible post formatting up front I am having to use my phone as I can’t access the internet on my laptop.

So, I am connected to the WiFi, I typed in the password it accepted it and if I check in network manager I have a download speed of 187 mbps, shows a connection of Excellent. So it is getting some sort of signal. But when I open any application or go in my browser I get a “We’re having trouble finding that site” or “offline” status within apps. If I ping ‘8.8.8.8’ I get 100% packet loss and never make it out of my IP. I have reset network manager several times, I’ve flushed the DNS cache. I am not sure what else I can do. Just doesn’t make any sense that I would show a download speed and excellent connection status but not be able to access the internet.

I do not have this issue on this network with my other devices, and do not have this issue on this device on other networks, and haven’t had this issue on this network on this device before today.

Product: ASUS [ROG GU501GM](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/GU501GM/)  ([manual download](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/GamingNB/GU501GM/E13724_GU501GS_GM_A.pdf)) 07/31/2018

Output for ‘ip route’

```
Default via 192.168.0.1 dev br0 proto static metric 20425 linkdown 
Default via 10.150.0.1 dev wlol proto dhcp metric 20600
10.150.0.0/17 dev wlol proto kernel scope link src 10.150.119.140 metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown
172.17.0.0/16 dev br0 docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.51 metric 425 linkdown
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Output for `ping  192.168.0.1`

Just got icmp_seq=[1-50] Destination Host Unreachable

IPv4 Address: 10.150.119.140
And I am using an Enterprise WPA2 network

Output of `ip route 8.8.8.8`

> 8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev br0 src 192.168.0.51 uid 1000 cache

I stopped the Docker.service and MySQL.service and still nada. Even reset networkmanager

After the last step if I ran `ip route get 8.8.8.8` br0 was still the default.

So I disabled all the virtual controllers and now wlol is showing as the default controller

The output for `nmcli device show`

[image: output]

It is working now!!!! I guess disabling all of my virtual devices and restarting the network manager did it. Thanks for the help guys. I guess enterprise networks don’t like docked much. I guess i will have to deploy when I get home.

Comment: Basic info includes your release of Ubuntu, can you ping anything on your network?  (you won't be able to ping 8.8.8.8 if gateway route isn't defined - is it?)  eg. `ip route` shows a *default via* to a valid gateway? and can you ping that?

Comment: What is the IP address that's being assigned to your network device? Are you using access control lists in your router?

Comment: re: "download speed of 187 mbps" is connection speed to your wireless router... not download speed from the Internet.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting I literally cannot copy and paste and adding formatting tags is not super easy on a phone. I don’t have internet on my laptop how would I copy/paste?

Comment: Can you `ping 192.168.0.1`?

Comment: @K7AAY why the 2 spaces at the end of each line? Easier to paste the text, select the text, hit the {} formatting icon. And new comments don't shove old comments off of the screen.

Comment: For blockquotes .

Comment: @Brett Plemons, some phones can. some phones can't. Don't sweat it, but when you can, please paste results into your question after clicking [edit]. Also please put two space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well onscreen. Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Comment: All good I just downloaded the app, formatting is much simpler

Comment: @BrettPlemons you haven't answered my questions from 17 minutes ago.

Comment: I just updated the post to answer your question

Comment: Have you set up the proper `Wi-Fi Security` for your WPA2 Enterprise network?

Comment: Yes, I connect to this WiFi everyday on my phone and laptop, credentials are saved. I even forgot the network and reconfigured. Also connected to their insecure network and same issue

Comment: @BrettPlemons Isn't your network configuration for docker messing something up? Disable/remove these virtual interfaces and bridges (if you can) and see if that helps.

Comment: @BrettPlemons I see you edited the question - is your first default route using wlo1 right now? If not, make it so (delete the other one or change metrics) and see what happens.

Comment: Honestly the infrastructure at this university is terrible on almost every front, our university wide DB is run on SQLite for more than 75,000 students and employees. Most of our networking is run on Cat 3, and other than in our Engineering College (which has generous private funding) has computers no newer than 2007. But we want to be the “first cyber land grant university” good luck I say!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95691/discussion-on-question-by-brett-plemons-connected-to-wifi-but-cant-access-inter).

Answer (score 1):

If you can ping your gateway by running:

```
sudo ping $(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')
```

then this is nothing but a DNS issue, and accordingly you can just attempt a quick temporary fix by running

```
sudo echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf
```

This will likely not survive reboot if your resolv.conf is managed by NetworkManager for example but at least you will know right away that it is related to the way the DNS is getting resolved.

Comment: Yeah it is just saying a ping statement and nothing is happening, which means I am just not getting a connection right?

Comment: No! Well, actually in broad terms "yes, your connection is not available/broken" but if you are getting `Destination Host Unreachable` in the output of the ping command I posted, then that means you are not routing packets to the gateway of `wlol`. Could you retry the ping command with the interface (wlol)  option `sudo ping -I wlol $(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')` and see if your packets go through

Comment: Now I get a ‘ping: SO_BINDTODEVICE: Invalid argument’

Comment: alright, could you post the output of `ip route get 8.8.8.8`

Comment: thanks, I see what the problem is(or at the very least very likely mighty be), before I post the command to run for the fix, can you post output of `sudo nmcli device show` . If you need to cover up the names of your wifi connection etcs. just pick an alias and I will use that in the solution accordingly,.

Comment: Sorry if that is hard to read, was too much to type on my phone

Comment: no, I can read it fine but WAIT. Is your wlan interface `wlol` or `wlo1` because in the screenshot it looks like `wlo1` . I have encountered `wlo1` before, but assumed that `wlol` was the name you set yourself as an alias. Could you retry `sudo ping -I wlo1 $(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}')` just in case

Comment: Same thing, invalid argument. I didn’t name it myself

Comment: Ok, please first turn off all bridged interfaces with `sudo ip link set br0 down` and `sudo ip link set docker0 down` and `sudo ip link set virbr0 down` once they are down (double-check with `route` or the `ip route` commands and no other interface but `wlo1` should be listed) please try to again resolve a webaddress with `ping google.com` and if this resolves to proper IP and you get packets back, then please try your browser. If this does not work right away, and all the bridged interfaces are in fact down, please post outputs of `sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf ` and `sudo route`

Comment: Yeah I already had done that and it was working, I’m home now on my network